# Sitecore asp.net generic handler

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have a generic asp.net handler(.ashx) in my asp.net website.  I'm want to migrate this handler over into sitecore.  Can I just add it as I normally would in a asp.net website.  Or does sitecore require me to do something different?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add it just like any other .aspx page. If you notice a page not found on the url, trying adding your page to `<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="/sitecore/default.aspx|/trace.axd|.....|/myfile.ashx" />` in web.config

Comment: I don't see how I would set my navigateurl for my hyperlink...because it isn't part of my sitecore tree...

Comment: VJ: If you tell Sitecore to ignore the path, then you just use that as your navigateURL.  So if your handler was at the root of your "Website" directory, you could just use "/yourhandler.ashx" as the URL.

Comment: @CraigTaylor would I be able to tell sitecore to ignore the path just for this instance? Do you have any examples?

Comment: VJ: xoail actually provided the example.  You can update your "IgnoreUrlPrefixes" element in the web.config.  Just add a pipe (|) plus the name of your handler. ("myfile.ashx" in xoail's example)  Sitecore should then not try to resolve to an item when this URL is processed.

Comment: @CraigTaylor just to be clear.  I added a handler(.ashx) in my visual studio solution.  It isn't in my sitecore tree but it is under my website\controls folder.  When I call my handler( NavigateUrl="handler.ashx") it resolves as mysitecoreinstance\controls\handler.ashx....I don't want controls showing up in the url....so 2 questions: 1) am I doing this right. 2) is there a way I can avoid showing "controls" in the url? is that what ignoreurlprefixes does?